# error: package ******.******.***** does not exist

Tags: import, playframework, intellij-idea

Play Framework localhost:9000 result:

> error: package com.achimala.leaguelib.connection does not exist

The line of code in question is as follows:

> import com.achimala.leaguelib.connection.LeagueAccount;

Am I calling the import improperly?..Do I need some identifier somewhere?

Comment: Did you pick the tags randomly?

Comment: I have solved this by these steps: #1: close play framework.  #2: open run command.  #3 Navigate to my project in command console. #4: type: "play clean-all"   #5: type: "play ~run".          Basically, I was updating the files in intellij, but play framework wanted to do it's own changes so my directories were corrupt until I cleaned them.